# How to fix Google Cloud ssh "module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to use google Datalab, however when I run the datalab create command, I get the following error:

```
(base) oimtiaz@omars-MBP ~ % datalab connect ai-adventures --port 8082
Connecting to ai-adventures.
This will create an SSH tunnel and may prompt you to create an rsa key pair. To manage these keys, see 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys
module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

It seems to be an error in the Python version, but I am unclear on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I discovered that the Google Cloud SDK does not support more recent versions of Python, so I needed to downgrade to 3.7 in order to use the needed features.